# On click of Summary Link want to open a modal popup

Tags: sharepoint-designer, modal-dialog

I have a Summary Link web part. On click of one of the links in the webpart I want an `aspx` page to be opened as a modal pop up.

The challenge is where to put this javascript code?

Answer (score 1):

On the same page where you have `Summary Link WebPart`, you can place a `Content Editor Web Part` which you can utilize to write down JavaScript code.

Have a read on how to [Add Script into a Content Editor Web Part (CEWP) in SharePoint](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/05/09/adding-script-into-a-content-editor-web-part-cewp-in-sharepoint-2010-aspx/)

Answer (score 1):

You can put down the code in a js reference it directly in the `aspx` page. The js file can be put the `Style Library`.

Another option is to put the `js` code in a Script Editor WebPart. Just add the webpart > Edit webpart > add snippet in a `<script>` tag

This cant be done with Content Editor Webpart without embedding ( setting a html as a source to CEWP)

[Refer this for using the script editor web part](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/05/20/how-to-use-script-editor-web-part-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to create your own XSL template in ItemStyle.xsl file (/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets), where you can adjust your custom script.